# Add Transparent and stretched Image to Imagelist in Delphi

Tags: image, delphi, transparent, stretch, imagelist

According to my previous question with the help of Cosmin Prund, I found how to stretch Image and add to ImageList:

```
procedure LoadDatasetImagesToImageList;
var 
  StretchedBMP: TBitmap;
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ImageList.Clear;
  ItemsDts.First;
  StretchedBMP := TBitmap.Create;
try

  // Prepare the stretched bmp's size
  StretchedBMP.Width := ImageList.Width;
  StretchedBMP.Height := ImageList.Height;

  // Prepare the memory stream
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    ImageBitmap:= TBitmap.Create;
    try
      while not ItemsDts.Eof do
      begin
        if not ItemsDtsPicture.IsNull then
        begin
          MS.Size := 0;
          ItemsDtsPicture.SaveToStream(MS);
          MS.Position := 0;
          ImageBitmap.LoadFromStream(MS);
          // Stretch the image
          StretchedBMP.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, StretchedBmp.Width-1, StretchedBmp.Height-1), ImageBitmap);
          ImageList.Add(StretchedBmp, nil);
        end;
        ItemsDts.Next;
      end;
    finally 
      ImageBitmap.Free;
    end;
  finally 
    MS.Free;
  end;
finally
  StretchedBMP.Free;
end;
```

Now the problem is that inserted Image is not transparent in ImageList. When displaying Items in a TListview, images are not transparented.
But when adding images normally (without stretching and using StretchedBMP variable) images are transparent.

PS: the link to the previous question is: [Add stretched image to ImageList in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675841/add-stretched-image-to-imagelist-in-delphi)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You call `ImageList.Add` and pass `nil` for the mask image. You can either calculate the mask corresponding to your stretched image, or you can call [`ImageList.AddMasked`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ImgList.TCustomImageList.AddMasked) instead to have the image list calculate a mask for you based on a color that you designate as the "transparent" color. That's what happens when you use the image-list component editor at design time.

Comment: Thanks it worked for Bitmap images (TBitmap).
But can you tell what should I do for Icon images? (TIcon)

Comment: OK. It seems I don't need to resize Icon files. I am using the above code just for bitmaps. Icons are automatically resized.

Comment: nowadays it's most common to have transparency in the alpha channel of a 32 bit image and so the mask is ignored.

Comment: I'm using PNGs with transparent backgrounds, however when using `ImageList.AddBitmap(TBitmap, nil, clNone, false, false)` I get a completely black icon.
Do I need to use masks when the image is already transparent? If so, how? Using clNone as background color?

Comment: Yes, @Dialex, you need a mask because PNG images use alpha transparency, not a simple bit mask. PNG images can have *partially* transparent pixels, so you need a mask to say which partially transparent pixels are transparent and which are opaque. You can ask how to create a mask for a PNG image by posting a question on Stack Overflow.